# How can one create a chart / report in Splunk which has many series? Is it possible?

Tags: splunk

I would like to create a report / line chart in Splunk which shows mulitple series of data points for weekly loads.  Below is a simple example in a spreadsheet, but I am having difficulty finding if this is even possible in Splunk and if so, how it could be implemented.  I am using

`"| dbquery mydatabaseconn "Select load_date, source, sum(transactions) from mytable group by load_date, source "`

as my Search.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible in Splunk. From the documentation chapter [Data structure requirements for visualizations](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.3.1/Viz/Datastructurerequirementsforvisualizations):

> Column, line, and area charts are two-dimensional charts supporting
>   one or more series. They plot data on a Cartesian coordinate system,
>   working from tables that have at least two columns. In tables for
>   column, line, and area charts, the first column contains x-axis values
>   and subsequent columns contain y-axis values (each column represents a
>   series).

So your data will need to look something like:

```
2015-10-01, 25, 17
2015-10-01, 50, 45
etc.
```

where column 2 represents "Source 1" and column 3 represents "Source 2".